# JavaScript not functioning in html pg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a page about astrology and want the user to input their sign. I created an if statement and when I try it out nothing outputs to my page. Essentially what I am trying to do is get it to print out "you are most compatible with ___" after typing in a sign.The following is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Astrology</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="row header">

 <a href="index.html"> <img src="header.png" alt="logo" /> </a>
 <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="horoscope.html">Horoscope</a></li>
 <li><a href="Compatability.html">Compatability</a></li>
 <li><a href="signs.html">Signs</a></li>
 <li><a href="aboutus.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>

<h1><center>Type your Sign </center></h1>
<input id="sign" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit!</button>
<p id="restults"></p>


<script>
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
var sign = document.getElementById("sign").value;
var results = document.getElementById("results");

 if (sign == taurus)
{
results.innerHTML =  " you are most compatible with cancer " ;
}
else {
results.innerHTML= "please enter a valid sign";

}




}

</script>





<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You need to add library first and then your `script` code.

2.`<p id="restults"></p>` need to be `<p id="results"></p>`.

3.`taurus` need to be `'taurus'`

Working example:-

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  var sign = document.getElementById("sign").value;
  var results = document.getElementById("results");

   if (sign == 'taurus')
  {
  results.innerHTML =  " you are most compatible with cancer " ;
  }
  else {
  results.innerHTML= "please enter a valid sign";

  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Astrology</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
     </head>
    
     <body>
    
      <div class="row header">
    
       <a href="index.html"> <img src="header.png" alt="logo" /> </a>
       <nav>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="horoscope.html">Horoscope</a></li>
       <li><a href="Compatability.html">Compatability</a></li>
       <li><a href="signs.html">Signs</a></li>
       <li><a href="aboutus.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
       </nav>
       </div>
    
      <h1><center>Type your Sign </center></h1>
      <input id="sign" type="text">
      <button id="submit" type="button">Submit!</button>
      <p id="results"></p> <!-- not restults-->
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: oh I definitely see where that could be wrong but unfortunately the "you are most compatible" part is still not appearing

Comment: It works now ! Thank you so much have a great day :)

Comment: @Christine glad to help you.have a great day :):)

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery for onclick listeners. Input this in your page's header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and change the scripts as;

```
 $('submit').click(function(event) {
    var sign = document.getElementById("sign").value;
    var results = document.getElementById("results");

    if (sign == 'taurus')
    {
        results.innerHTML =  " you are most compatible with cancer " ;
    }
    else {
        results.innerHTML= "please enter a valid sign";
    }
});
```